# BackGrond gets distored while building application in code name one

Tags: codenameone

I am building a application in codename one which has a log-in age.

I have a created a UI as the requirements but when i build the application from codename one's server for android then i see that a streamed background image gets distorted and convert in to lines. 
The background image has a gradient from 3 dimension to center top.

I checked it in codename one simulator its looks fantastic but in android emulator background image gets distorted.

Please check attached image for it. i have added two image 1st is of codename one's emulator and 2nd one is android emulator.
[image]

Please let me know that i do.

Answer (score 0):

You have a background gradient, the devices have a limited number of colors so the background will be distorted to some degree as the colors are adapted to the lower color count on the device.

This is assuming you didn't use a mutable image or a round rect border (not image border), in those two cases the number of colors might be lower because of drawing to an image surface that might be 16bit.